# Jmeter - java coding. How to get output data?

Tags: java, apache, maven, jenkins, jmeter

I try to use the Jmeter open source + java to emulate the stress tests and run them from Jenkins. The project is built ny Maven so I haven't the problems with Jenkins. but I can't catch the output info after sending the requests to the server.

```
 public void runTest( String url,String user,int URLnumber) {
    StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    // jmeter.properties
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("./jmeter.properties");

    HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();

    // HTTP Sampler
    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
    httpSampler.setDomain(url);
    //httpSampler.setPort(80);
    httpSampler.setPath("/");
    httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
    httpSampler.addArgument("post_id","51015");
    httpSampler.addArgument("variant","");

    // Loop Controller
    TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController();
    ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
    ((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
    ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true);

    // Thread Group
    SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(25);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(5);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl);

    org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser summariser = new Summariser();

    // Test plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");

    hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
    hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
    hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
    hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);

    jm.configure(hashTree);

    jm.run();
}
```

May be somebody knows how to configure the Jmeter by Jenkins without coding and get the results in the Jenkins console. But I think it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) which does support JMeter?

If it's unsuitable for any reason, Jenkins can execute at least following targets:

1. Shell script
2. Ant task
3. Maven profile

JMeter can be launched via all of above methods without having to write a single line of Java code. See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for details.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the console output during a jmeter test run is suppressed.

I suggest you have a look at the below link for jenkins configuration.

- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-maven-jenkins/

Hope this will help.